# Paste and Copy, how do I configure Ubuntu 22.04 to use ctrl_c, ctrl_v for copying en pasting in Libre office or other apps?

Tags: copy, paste

How do I configure Ubuntu 22.04 to use ctrl_c, ctrl_v for copying en pasting in Libre office or other apps?

Comment: The Ctrl+C and Ctrl+V are the default, except for the Terminal app. You don't have to do anything. Please explain what you have done.

Answer (score 2):

There is no need to configure this. These systemwide shortcut keys are used by default for copying (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>) and pasting (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>). Also the more old-style shortcuts, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Insert</kbd> and <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Insert</kbd> work.

Answer (score 0):

After 2 times reinstalling Ubuntu22042 I did find out........
The Fn and Ctrl keys are switchted on my Lenovo L440.....
Thnx for answering